# SQLAlchemy quoting of table names - Can't redefine 'quote' or 'quote_schema' arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

Whilst upgrading from sqlalchemy 0.8 to 1.0.4 my ORM has broken with the error Can't redefine 'quote' or 'quote_schema' arguments

I connect to a sybase db, and use a declarative_base

```
Base = declarative_base()
```

Using a standard method to create the mapping below

```
class RiskAggregationGroup(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'RISK_AGGREGATION_GROUP'
    __table_args__ = {'quote':False,'extend_existing':True}

    id = Column(Integer, name='id_risk_agg', primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), name='nm_risk_agg')
    description = Column(String(100), name='tx_desc')
```

This worked fine in sqlalchemy 0.8 but breaks in 1.0.4 as it doesn't like me specifying quote as a table arg.  I've tried a whole host of things to get around this, setting it in the base, e.g.

```
class Base(object):

    __table_args__ = {'quote':False,'extend_existing':True}

Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)
```

throws the same error.  If I change it to use the @declared_attr the quoting is not turned off.  I'm unable to change the sybase settings and my table names are all caps (which is the cause of the quoting).  I've got about 20 tables defined here, so am loathe to change them all to Table creations, such as:

```
class RiskAggregationGroup(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'RISK_AGGREGATION_GROUP'

    __table__ = Table(__tablename__, Base.metadata, 
    Column(Integer, name='id_risk_agg', primary_key=True, key='id'),
    Column(String(50), name='nm_risk_agg', key='name'), quote=False)
```

Does anyone have a more elegant solution, so far google has failed me?

Answer (score 5):

Got an answer to this from the sqlalchemy google group

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/xIPnU89GKFI

Huge thanks Michael Bayer.  Solution is to Not set quote:False, but to set the quote characters to [].

```
e = create_engine("sybase://")

# if not using quote=False, this will change the quoting character
e.dialect.identifier_preparer.initial_quote = '['
e.dialect.identifier_preparer.final_quote = ']'
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm dealing with an ancient Sybase DB and this has helped a lot. I set both of them to `''` as I wasn't sure why you used block brackets. Maybe newer versions of SQLAlchemy already handle this?

Comment: Yeah, I'm dealing with an Oracle database. I want to insert data into an existing table. I also set both of them to ''. Now, Oracle is at least accepting the identifiers.